# "Cowboy" as an adjective?

Tags: meaning, phrases, adjectives

I forget what phrases it's used in, but I'm pretty sure I've heard cowboy used an adjective to describe something someone made (most likely something poorly shimmed together on the road, just good enough to work).

Can anyone recall any usages of the word this way, or provide a proper definition? I've searched the definition of cowboy on many sites, but they all only provide definitions for it as a noun and verb.

EDIT: I AM NOT TALKING ABOUT DESCRIBING A PERSON AS A COWBOY, DONT CLOSE THIS QUESTION!

Comment: You can use cowboy as a modifier (working as an adjective) to say cowboy style (cowboy hat, cowboy outfit, cowboy boots) or when you want to say rustic, or hardy, or hearty (cowboy lunch, cowboy code, all the finesse of a cowboy).

Comment: That's a good point, I didn't think about that way, though it's not exactly what I'm thinking of

Comment: In the UK, at least, the term is applied to shoddy workmen, often with the implication that they are not qualified to do the work they have been contracted to do. It is particularly applied to people in the construction trades and then mostly to domestic scale contractors. Sentences like "I had a set of cowboy builders in to do my extension, getting it sorted cost me twice as much again.

Comment: UK Lexico has "British informal A dishonest or careless person in business, especially an unqualified one." With several examples of it used attributively. But I can't link directly, you need to select UK English and search

Comment: Answers to the alleged duplicate question are full and thorough, illustrating noun and adjective use. Reopening seems unlikely to bring up much new material.

Comment: @Anton No, they're all about people.

Comment: I agree with @Anton: the duplicate is sufficient. The question could also have been closed for lack of research, as all dictionary definitions I've looked at are quite specific in saying that the adjectival usage is in connection with a *person*. English being the flexible language it is, it would of course be acceptable to use the adjective to describe a *thing*, in the sense that the thing has the characteristics suggestive of (e.g.) the shoddy work of a cowboy tradesperson or outfit. Such usage is normal, and again demonstrates the OP's lack of research.

Comment: And -1 for editing the question to SHOUT at us.

Comment: Then you don't understand the usage I'm talking about, and shouldn't be answering the question. And what other recourse do I have when you just close my question without even understanding it?

Comment: No. Not cowboy builder. It's not about a person.

Comment: (1) Attributive nouns, aka noun modifiers, have been covered in depth on ELU.  This is the usage in 'a cowboy builder', say. (2) You will find the corresponding definition ('dishonest or careless person in business, especially an unqualified one') in any dictionary. Any claiming it has converted fully to an adjective is wrong; it is a noun modifier, classed under 'noun'. A transferred usage occurs: 'The plumber did a cowboy job' / 'The guitarist [Pat McGlynn] refused to pay his local council after what he claims was “a cowboy job" ...

Comment: [[Deadline Scotland](https://deadlinescotland.wordpress.com/2010/07/28/17342-3296/)]  // Close-voting on lack of understanding of a commonly addressed (on ELU) usage, and lack of research shown.

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/cowboy) gives an example using the transferred 'of the standard one would expect from a dishonest/careless/unqualified builder/plumber/...' definition: ‘Someone had re-roofed one chamber, a real cowboy job.’

Comment: Since no one seems to understand what you are asking for, it might help if you give a sentence in which the use of 'cowboy' is as you think works. You can make up a sentence but it is better if you find the use somewhere and give us a link.

Comment: It's only used in specific phrases,  which i can't remember.

Comment: More fun is the verb: You better cowboy up there, man. :)

Answer (score 2):

> I've heard cowboy used an adjective to describe something (most likely
> **something poorly shimmed together on the road, just good enough to
> work**).

Many nouns can be used attributively as modifiers, as in *cowboy boots*, meaning typical of, or referring to, a cowboy or cowboy style.

It appears, however, that **cowboy** as a modifier can also mean *jury-rigged, improvised, expedient, suboptimal*, etc. as illustrated in the following examples of *cowboy* modifying *solution*, *IT,* and *engineering*. (I'm not sure how the expression is being used in the math examples, where it is contrasted with *stretched out solution*. Perhaps it is an allusion to *lassoing* or *lassoing in*.)

> "The people we are looking for," explained the EDS futurist Jeff
> Wacker, "are people who can not only catch a problem, but quickly come
> up with a solution that will fix the problem for good, so it will
> never happen again...They see the problem, stop the problem, and then
> redesign the system so that that particular problem never, ever
> happens again—and it can't be a **cowboy solution**." [Thomas
> Friedman; *The World is Flat*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_World_Is_Flat_Further_Updated_and_Ex/-mv_ryTuvo0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22a%20cowboy%20solution%22&pg=PA292&printsec=frontcover) (2007)

> Note that if a > 0, we get a straight-stretched out solution, with y
> = 0; whereas if a < 0, we get a **cowboy solution**, with ... [S. Jalnapurkar; *Modeling and Stabilization for Mechanical Systems*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Modeling_and_Stabilization_for_Mechanica/pBpNAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22a%20cowboy%20solution%22&dq=%22a%20cowboy%20solution%22&printsec=frontcover)
> (1999)

> The solution on the left is called the *stretched out* solution, whereas
> the one on the right is the ***cowboy solution***. [Lawrence Sirovich;
> *Trends and Perspective in Applied Mathematics*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Trends_and_Perspectives_in_Applied_Mathe/dHHrBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22cowboy%20solution%22&pg=PA267&printsec=frontcover) (2012)
> [See the two illustrations on the next page.]

> The **cowboy solution** of solving problems through violence also
> links Holly to Harry's own more rationalized state and corporate
> violence, seconded by the fascist BaronKurtz, a fan who carries a copy
> of Martin's The Oklahoma Kid. [D. Broe; *Class, Crime and
> International Film Noir*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Class_Crime_and_International_Film_Noir/G9-vAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22cowboy%20solution%22&pg=PT72&printsec=frontcover)

> Moreover, what IT specialists inside the organization deemed
> “**cowboy** IT" reigned: **rogue** IT specialists implanted in locations
> outside OMES headquarters would regularly **jury-rig a solution to a
> problem**... [C. Fussell and C. Goodyear; *One Mission*](https://www.google.com/search?q=cowboy%20solution%20jury-rigged&tbm=bks&sxsrf=APq-WBsQQH9BIVthTIGcASpIceGeL5bI2A%3A1644603021232&ei=jaYGYprNDcqvqtsPoNavyAM&ved=0ahUKEwjax4HXn_j1AhXKl2oFHSDrCzkQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=cowboy%20solution%20jury-rigged&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQ4whY7RBgvBJoAHAAeACAAWWIAeQGkgEDOS4xmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-books) (2017)
> (Snippet view)

> I asked the metal benders to make me up a small scoop that we could
> install under the screen, and force more air in to the system. We did,
> and it worked like a champ. We had it painted to match the ship and I
> anticipated that the CO would be quite pleased. He viewed it as
> "**cowboy** engineering", and I had another black mark. [A. Wagner and
> U Wagner; *Aloft*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Aloft/Sl-r1Q1jaloC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22cowboy%20engineering%22&pg=PA177&printsec=frontcover) (2005)

> It is interesting to note that in the same way that we might dismiss
> this as '**cowboy** engineering', the control and data acquisition
> systems with which many of us are comfortable, are equally readily
> dismissed as 'North Seaed' by some of these smaller Gulf opererators.
> [*Subsea Control and Data Acquisition '98*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Subsea_Control_and_Data_Acquisition_98/e04ZAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22cowboy%20engineering%22&dq=%22cowboy%20engineering%22&printsec=frontcover) (1998)

Comment: “Cowboy solution” is *not* an expression; *solution* is just another noun like many others that can collocate with *cowboy* as an attributive noun.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Rereading the examples and finding others, I agree and propose the meaning of cowboy as a modifier here is "expedient/jury-rigged/temporary" as examples illustrate--in any case differing from the "reckless/flamboyant" sense documented in the Partridge Dictionary and the "unscrupulous" sense in the Collins and OED.

Answer (score 1):

It's chiefly British slang.  A label given to an incompetent worker, especially in the building trade. It usually refers to the person who does the job, or makes the object. I can't think of any examples where a shoddy object has been called 'cowboy'  but I suppose it's possible.

[Cowboy Builder](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/cowboy-builder)

> British English informal a house builder with no proper training or official QUALIFICATIONS who does work of a low standard
> Do-it-yourself decorators and cowboy builders are ruining Britain’s historic towns.

Some examples:

[Cowboy builders: 13 telltale signs so you can avoid them](https://www.realhomes.com/advice/cowboy-builders)

Cowboys  (UK sitcom)
"If a job's worth doing it's worth doing wrong"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6R7V2nYaCQ&list=PLheCx_qszp38FZ6nJKTRXxGjC1yz8BUCa

[Cowboy Builders](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1870738/)  (UK investigative show, exposing incompetent workers)

Comment: So, basically jerry-built? [funny, huh?]

Answer (score 1):

> **cowboy** (adj.)
>
> **reckless, impulsive, flamboyant** *US*
>
> *To shoot a man off his front doorstep, without the mapped-out getaway,
> the "hot" car, the other fine details carefully worked out, was a
> truly a "**cowboy** job."*—Burton Turkus and Sid Feder, *Murder, Inc.* p.9,
> 1951
>
> [T. Dalzell and T. Victor; *The New Partridge Dictionary of
> Slang and Unconventional English*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_New_Partridge_Dictionary_of_Slang_an/bbcBCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=cowboy%20as%20an%20adjective&pg=PA559&printsec=frontcover) (2015)

---

> "The media played you up as a hero. Back here in the office, I got
> reamed. You know how it is with the new chief—better to go by the book
> and have a negative outcome than do some **cowboy** stunt that works.”
> [Mark Schorr; *Fixation*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Fixation/4zzWI6_6wzsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22cowboy%20stunt%22&pg=PA187&printsec=frontcover) (2008)

> As he turned to give the order, Langston said, “Actually sir, Spiros
> and I don't really see eye to eye, and like you said, we don't need
> any **cowboy** heroics. Just give me a man with a cool head, who'll do
> what I say. [Peter Harmyk; *A Wind Through Paradise*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Wind_Through_Paradise/AXXyugan0HcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22cowboy%20heroics%22&pg=PA219&printsec=frontcover) (2004)

> America, with its lush life of sunshine and fruit and dance orchestras
> and comely women and bathrooms and cocktail bars and exuberant
> inductions into army life and **cowboy** maneuvers and brass bands and
> epic military exercises, was remote and unreal to them. [James
> Wellared; *General George S. Patton*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/General_George_S_Patton_Jr/OfkwDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22cowboy%20maneuvers%22&pg=PT105&printsec=frontcover) (2017)

---

> **cowboy** (n.)

> *Informal* **a.** a person who is an irresponsible or unscrupulous operator in business **b.** (***as a modifier***) *cowboy contractors;
> cowboy shop steward*
>
> Collins print dictionary

> A person without qualifications who competes against established
> traders or operators, providing shoddy goods or services usually at
> low (or inflated) prices; one who is recklessly unscrupulous in
> business. Frequently *attributive. slang.* (OED)

Comment: This is more the occupational version. The version referred to is originally American but commandeered by British English in the American sense of *A boisterous or wild young man. Also specifically a reckless or inconsiderate driver of a motor vehicle, esp. a lorry.* slang (originally U.S.). *1942   Amer. Speech 17 103/1   Cowboy, reckless driver.* --This was then transferred, in BE, as an epithet to anyone who did careless work.

Comment: @Greybeard Collins definition added.